# LoadError when trying to get source code in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate2

Trying to teach myself Ruby and using the Book Apress Beginning Ruby. I bought TextMate 2 and in the very beginning of Chap. 4 I am being asked for following:

1. Launch Terminal (Completed)
2. Use cd to navigate to the folder where you placed example1.rb, like so:cd ~/ruby. This tells Terminal to take you to the ruby folder located off of your home user folder. (Can't figure this out. What is "cd". Where do I type this TextMate 2 or Terminal. Do I type irb prior? I saved the example1.rb on my desktop, tried to drag and drop, says permission denied).
3. Type ruby example1.rb and press Enter to execute the example1.rb Ruby script.
4. If you get an error such as ruby:No such file or directory -- example1.rb (LoadError), you aren’t in the same folder as the example1.rb source file, and you need to establish where you have saved it. (Obviously I get this error, but I can't complete step 2).

Was super excited getting through chap 1-3 and using irb and now I bought TextMate2 and I get stuck trying to start my first ruby app.

Can anyone help explain Step 2 so I can complete 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is "cd"

cd is change directory command. Type it in your terminal like this:

> cd /dir/that/has/example1.rb

If example1.rb is in your Desktop and you are using Mac and your username is tom, then cd command would be:

> cd /Users/tom/Desktop

Then from the terminal again, type:

> ruby example1.rb

to run your Ruby script.